# custom formats to hide threejs software backend working

Tags: security, three.js

To render on threejs, we need some images(jpg/png) and , jsons(uv data). All these files are stored in respective folders and the files visible for clients to look at.

I use django/python to start a local server, python code is compiled to .pyc & js code is obfuscated. But the folder structure is accessible for Casual Users. In threejs, we use tex_loader and json_loader functions to which the file paths are given as inputs. Was looking at ways of securing the behind the scenes work.

- Happened to read about custom binary formats, but that felt like a lot of work.
- or giving access to files only for certain process starting through django/web browser?

Are there any available easy to deploy solutions to protect our IP ?

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to only serve the files to authenticated users. This could be achieved by having an endpoint on your backend like:

```
api/assets/data.json
```

and the controller in the backend would receive the file name(`data.json`), the code could check if the user requesting the endpoint is authenticated and if so read the file from the file system(`my-private-folder/assets/data.json`) and return it as file with correct mime-type to the browser.

Comment: May be I was not clear, the code is sitting on client's system. I locally run the server & open local host(127.0.0.1:8000) in web browser. my-private-folder will be  accessible to client through their file explorer. Will I be able to change the permissions of that folder so that only my application can access them. 

How to make my-private-folder inaccessible to file explorer? Do I have to do a chmod of sorts?

Comment: What platform is used? windows or a linux based os?

Comment: Our clients are on windows32, windows64 & Mac as well. 

How about this idea , By default chmod 000 for the private-folder files. When the application is running and tries to access the files, chmod 777 & once the work is done chmod back to 000. Is this very hacky ?

Comment: You could create a separate user for the application and only give that used permission for the folder. I am unsure if this is easily achieved on all platforms. Is maybe encrypting the data is an option? Only the application would be able to decrypt it if needed.